# Use ASP.NET Routing AND Rewriting in same Project

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, routes

i have a running Onlineshop which uses ASP.NET 4.5 and URL Rewriting via the web.config's rewrite-section.

As i am now adding some new parts to the shop i would like to use Routing (from System.Web.Routing) without changing the old (and running) code.

If i add some MapPageRoutes to the RouteCollection they never get fired as the Rewrites will fetch them and do the rewriting.I also added a ignore rewrite to the needed URLs, but this did not help.

Current Rewrites:

```
/test
/test/123
/test/123/edit
```

new Routes

```
/test2
/test2/123
...
```

Is the mixture possible within one Aebapplication and how can i get the Rewriting to ignore the Routes?

thank you for any hint
Christoph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both theoratically without a problem. According to [iis.net](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing)

> The technologies (routing and url rewriting) can be used together and can complement each other.

However, it is not recommended because it may cause conflicts as some implementations of ASP.NET URL Routing internally use rewriting as well.

[Here](http://dotnet4hosting.asphostportal.com/post/ASPNET-4-Hosting-ASPHostPortal-Using-IIS7-URL-Rewrite-Module-with-ASPNet-Routing.aspx) you can find how to combine routing and rewriting together. And rewriting does not have to ignore routing, because you should define different conditions for each. My personal recommendation would be convert rewriting rules to routing because you will already perform some effort and how many rules could exist anyway.